# ¿Cómo convierto un texto a mayúsculas o minúsculas en Bash, zsh o OSX?

Tags: string, bash, macos, zsh

Con frecuencia debo modificar nombres de ficheros que he bajado para que tengan un formato acorde con el repo en el que estoy trabajando. No siempre trabajo con el mismo lenguaje, por lo que el formato no es siempre el mismo.

En cualquier caso, ¿cómo modifico un texto para que pase a minúsculas o mayúsculas?

En mi OSX intento

```
foo="bAr"
echo "${foo,,}"  # quiero minúsculas
echo "${foo^^}"  # quiero mayúsculas
```

Pero ninguna de las dos me funciona. ¿Cuál es la manera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bash 5

Si tienes Bash 5 puedes utilizar las siguentes opciones, que no son de POSIX:

```
# A minúsculas
${var,}   # 1.º
${var,,}  # todos

# A mayúsculas
${var^}   # 1.º
${var^^}  # todos
```

### Bash 3, sh, zsh

Si estás en OSX normalmente tienes Bash 3, donde la sintaxis `${var,}` o `${var^}` aún no había sido introducido. Lo mismo para sh o zsh. Por ello, debes utilizar alguna funcionalidad externa como `tr` (que **tr**aduce):

```
# A minúsculas
echo "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< ${var:0:1})${var:1}"  # 1.º
echo "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "$var")"              # todos

# A mayúsculas
echo "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${var:0:1})${var:1}"  # 1.º
echo "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "$var")"              # todos
```

---

### Ejemplos

#### Bash 5

A minúsculas

```
$ var="HOLA"
$ echo "${var,}"
hOLA
$ echo "${var,,}"
hola
```

A mayúsculas

```
$ var="adios"
$ echo "${var^}"
Adios
$ echo "${var^^}"
ADIOS
```

#### Bash 3, sh, zsh

A minúsculas:

```
$ var="HOLA"
$ echo "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< ${var:0:1})${var:1}"
hOLA
$ echo "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "$var")"
hola
```

A mayúsculas:

```
$ var="adios"
$ echo "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${var:0:1})${var:1}"
Adios
$ echo "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "$var")"
ADIOS
```